# PHP Non-blocking child process that terminates with parent

Tags: php, nonblocking, child-process

After looking around for a while, I have not found an answer to what I thought would be a simple thing to do.

I'm coding in PHP, and I need to start a child process from a parent. The child process must be non-blocking: the parent should be able to continue doing its processing while the child is running in the background. (Note that I cannot use process forking because the parent and the child are not the same process.) Once the parent has completed processing or **crashes unexpectedly**, the child process should be terminated.

I currently have this implemented using a detached child process, and it works quite well... that is, until the parent crashes. Over time, if many parents crash, a collection of unterminated child processes are rampaging the system like a horde of angry barbarians.

I cannot check whether an orphaned child process is already running and terminate it prior to launching the parent - there may be other parent processes running with their own children, and it's impossible to tell which parent is using which child and which child is an orphan.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have the child process check the parent is stall active every X seconds

Comment: How are you doing parent/child processing then if you can't use forking? Why can't you use forking? How do you expect to emulate process control if you aren't able to use the tools that do it in the first place? Also.. without some code to try and reproduce this behaviour, we can just guess around - and as you can see, the 2nd commenter already started asking about why not do it right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from N.B.'s comment and not knowing how this is coded, my only suggestion for how to handle it would be from the crash handling.  Is it crashing from an exception being thrown that you can catch either in the parent class or from where the parent class is being managed.  If so can you then close down your child processes from an exception handler there?  You should still have some kind of handle to get to the child processes from there, maybe.

Comment: Yes, the crashing happens from an exception in the parent caused by a malfunction in the child. Thanks for the tip. That's what I ended up doing.